I cannot login to the Visual Studio 2019 Community - I've tried everything - What's wrong?
I have an old PC that has a 32 bit processor and I need to use Visual Studio on this PC. I installed VS 2019 offline from a USB stick. 30 days after the trial period has ended. So I see a message in the screen;
"Sign in to use Visual Studio Community Edition for free".
When I try to sign in, I get an alert: "The online service is unavailable. Please try again later".
enter image description here
How can I solve this problem?
I've already tried these methods;
--> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/832154/visual-studio-2013-pro-the-online-service-is-not-a
but when I open the registry editor, I see that the .NET Framework folder is not located under the Microsoft folder (please see the screenshot below)
enter image description here
These methods did not work;
--> Change default web browser in Visual Studio
(change default browser)
--> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2022-cant-sign-in/1624070
(change proxy settings)
enter image description here
I have to say, Windows Defender and Windows Firewall are closed.

I would like to ask what is the actual OS version of your old PC with 32-bit processor? Can you provide VS activity logs according to the guidance in this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/log-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019

Hi @Codyliang , When I follow this path, I see this, do you have any idea what I should do https://ibb.co/nzsCxtb   https://ibb.co/HD7Q6fs

I would like to ask what exactly this link in your comment points to, I can't get into this link.

I installed .NET Framework 4.8 and the problem was solved.
